# Defining when onclick is fired

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I am having a little issue with something.  I have a form, and I map the fields of the form within a system.  The button of the form is automatically given an onclick event like this

```
window.location='http://www.something.com/test.html?vs=ZWJhMDAzMzktMTNkYi00ODRkLTgxYmQtNjQwYTU5MDIyZWE3OzA6ODc5NjY2NzoxMjg2NzUyNDM3NDI6OTAxNzM0MzA1OjkwMTczNDMwNTsS1'
```

It adds a vs variable which is needed.  The problem is I need the form to have an input type button, not submit.  I am using JQuery validation and I have this to trigger the form submission

```
$("#btn-default2").click(function() {
        $("#myform").submit();
    });
```

Now the issue with this, because of the onclick event, the validation quickly fires and then the onclick event does a redirect.  I only want this redirect if the form is valid.  Is there any way to stop the event onclick, and move it into my function where I check if the form is valid?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A procedural answer for your problem,

```
var btn = $("button.validate");
var x = btn.attr("onclick"); //get the onclick and store it in a variable.
btn.attr("onclick", ""); //remove the onclick attribute for that button
btn.click(function() {
    //Now do validations for your button.
    if ($("input[type='text']").val() == "10") { 
        eval(x); //If the form fields passed the validation
        //then trigger the redirect using eval
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/h2dhevcc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take advantage of jquery validation plugin then you should try using the submit handler.

The `submitHandler` is a callback function built into the plugin. Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit.

```
$("form").validate({

  submitHandler: function(form) {

  }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#btn-default2").click(function(){
    $(this).off("click");
});
```